# Automatically toggle between spans

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't find any answers that allow for `sentence here` followed by `end word`

The idea is that I'll have a list of items in a spans and then toggle between them, so the beginning of the sentence is the same and only the end changes. Ideally there would be some sort of animation but even just the functionality would be appreciated.

```html
<p class="itemlist">We sell
    <span class="items">
      <span>Bread</span>
      <span>Milk</span>
      <span>Fish</span>
      <span>Eggs</span>
      <span>Cheese</span>
    </span>
  </p>
```

Ideally I'd like it to show one item at a time. The end result would look like the GIF below but the text should remain in the same place.

[Gif of intention.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S7Hl.gif)

Any prompts/answers would be greatly appreciated. I'm tearing my hair out for two hours over this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is probably an image insted of text, and a carosel changing the image.- do this but make it automatic - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using setInterval

```js
let i=0;
const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.items span'));

const showNewItem = (index) => {
  items.forEach(i => i.style.display = 'none');
  
  items[index].style.display = 'inline';
}

// Initial call
showNewItem(i++);

setInterval(() => {
  showNewItem(i++);
  if(i > items.length-1) i = 0;
},1000);
```

```html
<p class="itemlist">We sell
    <span class="items">
      <span>Bread</span>
      <span>Milk</span>
      <span>Fish</span>
      <span>Eggs</span>
      <span>Cheese</span>
    </span>
  </p>
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll  accept forEach, no need to use Array.from(document.querySelectorAll ..

Comment: @MisterJojo yes, I was not sure if it had `length`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a delay. here is a sample code for that

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


 

 <p class="itemlist">We sell
    <span class="items">
      <span id="demo"> Bread</span>
      
    </span>
  </p>

<script>
 
 

var delayInMilliseconds1 = 1000; 
var delayInMilliseconds2 = 2000; 
var delayInMilliseconds3 = 3000; 

setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Milk";
}, delayInMilliseconds1);

setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Fish";
}, delayInMilliseconds2);

setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Eggs";
}, delayInMilliseconds3);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes setInterval is the key
[edit] text is now centered

```js
const All_span = document.querySelectorAll('p.itemlist span.items span');
var NoSpan = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    All_span[NoSpan++].style.display = 'none';
    NoSpan %= All_span.length;
    All_span[NoSpan].style.display = 'inline';
}, 900);
```

```css
p.itemlist {
 font: 2em Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 display: block;
 width: 8em;
 text-align: center;
}
p.itemlist span.items span {
 display: none;
 color:crimson;
}
p.itemlist span.items span:first-child {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p class="itemlist">We sell
 <span class="items">
  <span>Bread</span>
  <span>Milk</span>
  <span>Fish</span>
  <span>Eggs</span>
  <span>Cheese</span>
 </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var itemArray = ['Bread', 'Milk', 'Fish', 'Eggs', 'Cheese'];
var animationInterval;

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function setItemName(_name) {
  var itemList = document.getElementsByClassName('items')[0];
  itemList.textContent = _name;
}

function startAnimation() {
  animationInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var randomNumber = getRandomInt(itemArray.length);
    setItemName(itemArray[randomNumber]);
  }, 1000)
}

function endAnimation() {
  clearInterval(animationInterval);
}

setItemName(itemArray[0]);
```

```html
<p class="itemlist">We sell
    <span class="items"></span>
 </p>
  
<button onclick="startAnimation();"> Start </button>
<button onclick="endAnimation();"> End </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an item to start on using a class like "first"

Using jQuery, grab the items list, and set an interval to go through. Then fadeout the current active and fadein the next one.

Find the next element either just by grabbing the next sibling, or grabbing the first child of the items list if you reach the end.

```js
let itemsList = $(".items").first();

const changeItem = () => {
  let current = itemsList.find("span.active");
  current.removeClass("active");
  current.fadeOut(200, () => {
    let next;
    if (current.next().length > 0) next = current.next();
    else next = itemsList.children().first();
    next.addClass("active");
    next.fadeIn(200);
  });
}

setInterval(changeItem, 2000);
```

```css
.items span {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

span.first {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="itemlist">We sell
    <span class="items">
      <span class="active first">Bread</span>
      <span>Milk</span>
      <span>Fish</span>
      <span>Eggs</span>
      <span>Cheese</span>
    </span>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about decoupling data from HTML? and use `setInterval` then

```js
const itemList = ['Bread', 'Milk', 'Fish']
const prefix = "We Sell"

const placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
let index = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  index = index >= itemList.length ? 0 : index;

  placeholder.innerHTML = `${prefix} <span style='color: red'> ${itemList[index]} </span>`;

  index++;
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div id="placeholder" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For info, you could also use [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.items span {
  position: absolute;/* instead display */
  animation: var(--delay, 0) 10s hidsh linear infinite;
}

@keyframes hidsh {
  0%,
  80% {
    color: transparent;
  }
  80.1%,
  100% {
    color: initial
  }
```

```html
<p class="itemlist">We sell
  <span class="items">
      <span style='--delay:-2s' >Bread </span>
  <span style='--delay:-4s'>Milk  </span>
  <span style='--delay:-6s'>Fish  </span>
  <span style='--delay:-8s'>Eggs  </span>
  <span style='--delay:-10s'>Cheese</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

You may also declare the custom properties in the style sheet if you do not want to touch the HTML

```css
.items span              {--delay:-2s }
.items span:nth-child(2) {--delay:-4s }
.items span:nth-child(3) {--delay:-6s }
.items span:nth-child(4) {--delay:-8s }
.items span:nth-child(5) {--delay:-10s}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.items span {
  position: absolute;/* instead display*/
  animation: var(--delay, 0) 10s hidsh linear infinite;
}

@keyframes hidsh {
  0%,
  80% {
    color: transparent;/* instead visibility or opacity */
  }
  80.1%,
  100% {
    color: initial
  }
```

```html
<p class="itemlist">We sell
  <span class="items">
   <span>Bread </span>
   <span>Milk  </span>
   <span>Fish  </span>
   <span>Eggs  </span>
   <span>Cheese</span>
  </span>
</p>
```